# Using jQuery AJAX to Invoke Rails Server Method on Client Side

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am using Ruby on Rails, and I want to invoke a controller method as an `onclick` event of my pre-existing links.

I am using jQuery and AJAX to do the same. But I don't know much about AJAX.

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a.browse_history").live("click", function()
{
    alert("i am here");
    $.ajax({     
    url: "/user_profile_controller.rb/save_user_history",     
    type: 'PUT'   
    }); 
});
</script>
```

In `user_profile_controller.rb`:

```
def save_user_history 
  $doc_list << "hello hi"
end
```

And my link is:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/documents" id="browse_history" class="browse_history">Click here</a>
```

But this is not working..
Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL looks wrong. Run `rake routes` to get a list of existing routes in your app.

Should be something like

```
 url: "/user_profile/save_user_history"
```

or

```
 url: "/user_profiles/save_user_history"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply Stefan.

I changed my code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function u_profile(user,url,query)
{

    $.ajax({     
        type: 'POST' ,
        url: "http://localhost:3000/user_profiles",  
        data : {
            user_profile : {                         
                user_id : user ,                      
                query_term : query,
                visited_url: url
            }                     
        } ,  
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
};  
</script>
```

And i am invoking it as onclick event of  link.

It full fills my requirement of creating an object in database with passed data.